# Ways to improve inter app-service communication

Tags: azure, containers, cloud, azure-aks, app-service-environment

I have two app services(service A and Service B) developed in **.net core 3.1** and hosted as two independent app service in azure. Service A is heavily dependent on service B. Is there is way (Azure offering) to make them **communicate faster**? Is hosting them in **same container** will improve inter service communication performance?  Any suggestion on **kubernetes**?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Azure Kubernetes Offering yet, (AKS) I would recommend spinning up a cluster. (note that it supports windows nodes in case you need them)

You should keep your services separated into two pods (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads#pods)

and create a matching kubernetes service.

Now if you would like to have your POD run on the same node to increase the communication speed, you should look at using pod affinity, which will allow to have pod pods run on the same node, without having to tie them to a particular node (node affinity)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-advanced-scheduler#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity